# 'search_excerpt' type issues

Tags: bug, documentation

On the [`search_excerpt`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/search-excerpt) page:

- `community_owned_date` should be marked as *may be absent*
- `locked_date` should be marked as *may be absent*
- `search/excerpts` should be listed in the *Methods That Return This Type* section